# Sell a WooCommerce Product on Content Pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a product called "Business Cards" (`id="56"`) the user needs to make several selections before adding the product to their cart, such as quantity, paper type, size, etc.

I also have a content page for "Business Card Ideas" which is a page with different examples and styles of business cards. Would there be a way to add the ordering form (`<form class="cart">`) from the business cards product to this content page in such a way that the user could make all of their required selections and add the product to the cart without ever visiting the business cards product page?

Using `[add_to_cart id="56"]` does what I'm looking for, but you cannot make any selections. You can only add the product to the cart with the default selections.

Thanks in advance
Willem

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is likely to insert the whole product using `[product_page id="53"]`.

Comment: Thank you, but that's unfortunately not a viable option.